# Plotly fill area downwards

Tags: python, plotly-python

I'm rather new to plotly, having made a transition from matplotlib due to plotly's efficiency at working with Django.

I'm trying to create a figure where I fill in the area **below** my data values. this works fine whenever i have positive values, but when they are negative, the area is filled upwards (towards the x axis):

```
fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=1)
fig.add_scatter(
    x = [result.index[i] for i in range(len(result))],
    y = [result.obs.iloc[i] for i in range(len(result))],
    mode = 'lines',
    fill='tonexty')
```

[current figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lqxic.png)

UPDATE:
current fix:`    fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=1)

```
# Add the observed data trace
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        x=[result.index[i] for i in range(len(result))],
        y=[result.obs.iloc[i] for i in range(len(result))],
        mode='lines',
        name='Groundwater level'
    )
)

# Calculate the default minimum of the y-axis
default_y_min = result.obs.min()  # Use the minimum of observed data and 0
max_y = result.obs.max()
default_y_min = default_y_min - ((max_y - default_y_min)/3)
max_y = max_y + (max_y-default_y_min)/2

# Add the fill trace
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        x=[result.index[i] for i in range(len(result))],
        y=[default_y_min] * len(result),
        fill='tonexty',
        fillcolor='rgba(0, 100, 80, 0.2)',
        hoverinfo='skip',
        showlegend=False,
        line=dict(width=0)
    )
)`
```

This seems to work fine for now, but not sure about how the yaxis range will hold with other series.